# Join timeout in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a dummy example, I want to apply multiprocessing in it. Consider a scenario where you have a stream of numbers(which I call frame) incoming one by one. And I want to assign it to any single process that is available currently. So I am creating 4 processes that are running a `while` loop, seeing if any element in queue, than apply function on it.

The problem is that when I `join` it, it gets stuck in any `while` loop, even though I close the `while` loop before it. But somehow it gets stuck inside it.

Code:

```
# step 1, 4 processes
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import time

class MpListOperations:
    def __init__(self):
        self.results_queue = mp.Manager().Queue()
        self.frames_queue = mp.Manager().Queue()
        self.flag = mp.Manager().Value(typecode='b',value=True)
        self.list_nums = list(range(0,5000))


    def process_list(self):
        print(f"Process id {os.getpid()} started")
        while self.flag.value:
#             print(self.flag.value)
            if self.frames_queue.qsize():
                self.results_queue.put(self.frames_queue.get()**2)


    def create_processes(self, no_of_processes = mp.cpu_count()):
        print("Creating Processes")
        self.processes = [mp.Process(target=self.process_list) for _ in range(no_of_processes)]

    def start_processes(self):
        print(f"starting processes")
        for process in self.processes:
            process.start()

    def join_process(self):
        print("Joining Processes")
        while True:
            if not self.frames_queue.qsize():
                self.flag.value=False
                print("JOININNG HERE")
                for process in self.processes:
                    exit_code = process.join()
                    print(exit_code)
                print("BREAKING DONE")
                break

    def stream_frames(self):
        print("Streaming Frames")
        for frame in self.list_nums:
            self.frames_queue.put(frame)


if __name__=="__main__":
    start = time.time()
    mp_ops = MpListOperations()
    mp_ops.create_processes()
    mp_ops.start_processes()
    mp_ops.stream_frames()
    mp_ops.join_process()
    print(time.time()-start)
```

Now if I add a timeout parameter in `join`, even `0`, i.e `exit_code = process.join(0)` it works. I want to understand in this scenario, if this code is correct, what should be the value of timeout? Why is it working with timeout and not without it? What is the proper way to implement multiprocessing with it?

Comment: This isn't strictly answering the question. but a workaround could be by using the [Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) object? It allows to run a function against an input stream, which is essentially what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AlexLoss, can you provide a related coded example with Pool?

Comment: If you do not pass an argument to `join()` **or** pass it a *non-positive* number (like `0`), it doesn't block — that's why it works. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for a managed queue you will see that the `qsize` method only returns an approximate size. I would therefore not use it for testing when all the items have been taken of the frames queue. Presumably you want to let the processes run until all frames have been processed. The simplest way I know would be to put N *sentinel* items on the frames queue after the actual frames have been put where N is the number of processes getting from the queue. A sentinel item is a special value that cannot be mistaken for an actual frame and signals to the process that there are no more items for it to get from the queue (i.e. a quasi end-of-file item). In this case we can use `None` as the sentinel items. Each process then just continues to do get operations on the queue until it sees a sentinel item and then terminates. There is therefore no need for the `self.flag` attribute.

Here is the updated and simplified code. I have made some other minor changes that have been commented:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import time

class MpListOperations:
    def __init__(self):
        # Only create one manager process:
        manager = mp.Manager()
        self.results_queue = manager.Queue()
        self.frames_queue = manager.Queue()
        # No need to convert range to a list:
        self.list_nums = range(0, 5000)


    def process_list(self):
        print(f"Process id {os.getpid()} started")
        while True:
            frame = self.frames_queue.get()
            if frame is None: # Sentinel?
                # Yes, we are done:
                break
            self.results_queue.put(frame ** 2)


    def create_processes(self, no_of_processes = mp.cpu_count()):
        print("Creating Processes")
        self.no_of_processes = no_of_processes
        self.processes = [mp.Process(target=self.process_list) for _ in range(no_of_processes)]

    def start_processes(self):
        print("Starting Processes")
        for process in self.processes:
            process.start()

    def join_processes(self):
        print("Joining Processes")
        for process in self.processes:
            # join returns None:
            process.join()

    def stream_frames(self):
        print("Streaming Frames")
        for frame in self.list_nums:
            self.frames_queue.put(frame)
        # Put sentinels:
        for _ in range(self.no_of_processes):
            self.frames_queue.put(None)


if __name__== "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    mp_ops = MpListOperations()
    mp_ops.create_processes()
    mp_ops.start_processes()
    mp_ops.stream_frames()
    mp_ops.join_processes()
    print(time.time()-start)
```

Prints:

```None
Creating Processes
Starting Processes
Process id 28 started
Process id 29 started
Streaming Frames
Process id 33 started
Process id 31 started
Process id 38 started
Process id 44 started
Process id 42 started
Process id 45 started
Joining Processes
2.3660173416137695
```

**Note for Windows**

I have modified method `start_processes` to temporarily set attribute `self.processes` to `None`:

```py
    def start_processes(self):
        print("Starting Processes")
        processes = self.processes
        # Don't try to pickle list of processes:
        self.processes = None
        for process in processes:
            process.start()
        # Restore attribute:
        self.processes = processes
```

Otherwise under Windows we get a pickle error trying to serialize/deserialize a list of processes containing two or more `multiprocessing.Process` instances. The error is "TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object." This can be demonstrated with the following code where we first try to pickle a list of 1 process and then a list of 2 processes:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, number_of_processes):
        self.processes = [mp.Process(target=self.worker) for _ in range(number_of_processes)]
        self.start_processes()
        self.join_processes()

    def start_processes(self):
        processes = self.processes
        for process in self.processes:
            process.start()

    def join_processes(self):
        for process in self.processes:
            process.join()

    def worker(self):
        print(f"Process id {os.getpid()} started")
        print(f"Process id {os.getpid()} ended")


if __name__== "__main__":
    foo = Foo(1)
    foo = Foo(2)
```

Prints:

```
Process id 7540 started
Process id 7540 ended
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 26, in <module>
    foo = Foo(2)
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.start_processes()
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 13, in start_processes
    process.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
Process id 18152 started
Process id 18152 ended
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: Interesting. One question, Here, have you used the `None` as <i>Sentinal</i> value? From what I have experienced, if the queue is empty and we run `get`, in jupyter either it runs forever or gives an error. Not None, so do we have to insert `None` manually to set as senintinal?

Answer (score 1):

The target loop is stuck in the `get()` method of your loop. This is because multiple processes could see that the queue wasn't empty, but only 1 of them was able to get the last item. The remaining processes are waiting for the next item to be available from the queue.

You might need to add a `Lock` when you are reading the size of the `Queue` object And getting the object of that queue.

Or alternatively, you avoid reading the size of the queue by simply using the [`queue.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get) method with a timeout that allows us to check the `flag` regularly

```py
import queue

TIMEOUT = 1 # seconds

class MpListOperations:
    #[...]
    def process_list(self):
        print(f"Process id {os.getpid()} started")
        previous = self.flag.value 
        while self.flag.value:
            try:
                got = self.frames_queue.get(timeout=TIMEOUT)
            except queue.Empty:
                pass
            else:
                print(f"Gotten {got}")
                self.results_queue.put(got**2)
            _next = self.flag.value
            if previous != _next:
                print(f"Flag change: {_next}")
```

```
$ python ./test_mp.py
Creating Processes
starting processes
Process id 36566 started
Streaming Frames
Process id 36565 started
Process id 36564 started
Process id 36570 started
Process id 36567 started
Gotten 0
Process id 36572 started
Gotten 1
Gotten 2
Gotten 3
Process id 36579 started
Gotten 4
Gotten 5
Gotten 6
Process id 36583 started
Gotten 7

# [...]

Gotten 4997
Joining Processes
Gotten 4998
Gotten 4999
JOININNG HERE
Flag change: False
Flag change: False
Flag change: False
Flag change: False
Flag change: False
Flag change: False
Flag change: False
Flag change: False
Exit code : None
Exit code : None
Exit code : None
Exit code : None
Exit code : None
Exit code : None
Exit code : None
Exit code : None
BREAKING DONE
1.4375360012054443
```

Alternatively, using a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) object:

```py
def my_func(arg):
    time.sleep(0.002)
    return arg**2

def get_input():
    for i in range(5000):
        yield i
        time.sleep(0.001)

if __name__=="__main__":
    start = time.time()
    mp_pool = mp.Pool()
    result = mp_pool.map(my_func, get_input())
    mp_pool.close()
    mp_pool.join()
    print(len(result))
    print(f"Duration: {time.time()-start}")
```

Giving:

```
$ python ./test_mp.py
5000
Duration: 6.847279787063599
```

Comment: This makes sense. Are there any built-in locks inside multi-processing in Python? I have seen some examples, but not understood them.